# smoothdivscroll - image onclick not working

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using smoothdivscroll from smoothdivscroll.com and the onclick of an image inside a smoothdivscroller does not trigger in certain browsers.

```
<script>
function test() {
     alert("test click");   
}
</script>

<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img onClick="test()" src="http://fakeimg.pl/497x330/?text=Click me" alt="Field" id="field" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/gnome.jpg" alt="Gnome" id="gnome" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/pencils.jpg" alt="Pencils" id="pencils" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/golf.jpg" alt="Golf" id="golf" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/river.jpg" alt="River" id="river" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/train.jpg" alt="Train" id="train" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/leaf.jpg" alt="Leaf" id="leaf" />
    <img src="http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/images/demo/dog.jpg" alt="Dog" id="dog" />
</div>
<div>
    <img onClick="test()" src="http://fakeimg.pl/497x330/?text=Click me" alt="Field" id="field" />
</div>
```

I know of one that doesn't work:
Chrome 18.0.1025469 Android 4.1.1; SCH-I535 Build/JRO03L 
WebKit version: 535.19(git@30c8f76)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hr4U/279) is the jsfiddle (clicking the first image in the scroller should open alert):

Comment: On my browser it works. You can try changing "onClick" to "onclick", maybie it will work

Comment: No, that didn't work. It's seems like it's just the chrome on android and the iphone that doesn't work, although I haven't tested an iphone with this exact code. It works with my default browser on my galaxy s3.

Comment: I didn't knew that you are testing it on a mobile browser. Things works differently there, events are handled differently. You should use something like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) for better events handlers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to look into that. I figured it was something related to being mobile with a touch interface. Unfortunately I think the smoothdivscroller library will have to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with clickable links inside the scroller when using the touch interface is that you get an event conflict. Should pointing your finger on a link mean "I want to click this link" or does it mean "I put my finger here because I want to start scrolling".

I use [jQuery.kinetic](http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/) for the touch scrolling. Perhaps you could look at their page to see if there's a fix?